# filter objects by a specific date property in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects that have properties such as startDate, endDate.
I want to list objects in the given array that (for example) have an endDate in the past. I can't figure out how to use angularjs filters to achieve this. Any hints or examples are highly appreciated.

Comment: You want to filter based on system date or you are sending today's date from server?

Comment: What is the format of `startDate, endDate` ???

Comment: Post you code and create a plunker maybe.

Comment: Share more details as asked by A.J ,also if possible share some existing code which you have tried

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to help with your code simple but here is the way i would do it.

You could pass your array to a custom filter like this:

```
{{yourArray|yourDateFilter:parameterIfNeeded}}
```

Your filter can now loop through the date array.

- Convert your date to the right format.
- Compare with your parameter or whatever conditions you want.
- Build a new array with the objects you want.
- Return your array.